# Pass-by-value argument in message expression is undefined

Tags: iphone, objective-c, argument-passing

I'm developing an iPhone application and I getting that warning at method:

```
NSNumber *latitudeValue;
NSNumber *longitudeValue;

[self obtainLatitude:latitudeValue longitude:longitudeValue];
```

The method is declared as follows:

```
- (void) obtainLatitude:(NSNumber *)latitudeValue longitude:(NSNumber *)longitudeValue {

    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    latitudeValue = [f numberFromString:[latitude.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."]];
    longitudeValue = [f numberFromString:[longitude.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."]];

    [f release];
}
```

As you can see, I'm trying to calculate `latitudeValue` and `longitudeValue` calling `obtainLatitude:longitude:` but I'm doing something wrong.

How can I fix that error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Elfred's answer works, but pass-by-reference for non-NSError** parameters is pretty uncommon.   As well, coordinates -- numeric values, in general -- are most typically stored in regular old C types in structures because, comparatively, an NSNumber is quite a bit of overhead (no big deal for a few of 'em, would be a problem if you have a few dozen, hundred, or thousands of coordinates).

Something like:

```
struct MyLocation {
  CGFloat latitude;
  CGFloat longitude;
};
typedef struct MyLocation MyLocation;
```

Then:

```
- (MyLocation) mapCoordinates {
    MyLocation parsedLocation;

    parsedLocation.latitude = ....;
    parsedLocation.longitude = ....;

    return parsedLocation;
}
```

Something like the above would be more typical in an iPhone/Cocoa program.

As Dave points out, you really don't need to define your own type for this.  Use [CLLocationCoordinate2D or CLLocation.](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html)

Comment: +1 Or use a `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, which is pretty much the same thing (except it uses a double and not a float).

Comment: I use NSNumber to check if latitude.text is a valid number. If you know another way to check this, I'll use it.

Comment: Personally, I'd use just one number formatter to do conversion to NSNumber and then convert that to the scalar type used in CLLocationCoordinate2D.

Answer (score 2):

You are indeed passing the pointers by value, so when you reassign them, that just takes effect inside thee method. One alternative is to do the following:

```
- (void) obtainLatitude:(NSNumber **)latitudeValue longitude:(NSNumber **)longitudeValue {

    NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];

    *latitudeValue = [f numberFromString:[latitude.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."]];
    *longitudeValue = [f numberFromString:[longitude.text stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"," withString:@"."]];

    [f release];
```

}

then your call would look like:

```
NSNumber *latitudeValue;
NSNumber *longitudeValue;

[self obtainLatitude:&latitudeValue longitude:&longitudeValue];
```